# Unity3D - OSX External Editor w/ Line Number and Column

Tags: unity-game-engine

So some of the doc's and WIKI's I've read seem to claim that on OSX Unity will pass file, line, column by default as arguments when calling an External Editor.

I've written an .app via Automator on OSX which just runs the shell command:

```
/usr/local/bin/LaunchVSCode $1 $2 $3
```

The corresponding LaunchVSCode shell command just does the following for testing:

```
echo $1 >> /tmp/log.out
echo $2 >> /tmp/log.out
echo $3 >> /tmp/log.out
```

$2 and $3 are always blank for me when triggering the program from Unity.  ($1 is the filename as expected, but it's fairly useless without row and column args)

Did something change here?  I'm using Unity 5.0.

**Edit:**
Still banging my head on this and found http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/external-script-editor-what-apps-are-allowed.8073/#post-59474 which seems to imply Unity is looking for some API stuff on OSX now rather than just passing the arguments as they were previously.  Does that mean anything to anyone (because it certainly doesn't to me)?  Is this even possible to do anymore with a 'dumb' Automator .app anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use this as the called app from Unity, you will get line jumping:
https://github.com/CapnCromulent/VSCProxy